# Linearizing a 2nd order ODE

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I am an engineering student trying to understand the solution of the following problem:

I want to linearize the ODE

$$y''= f(y,y',u) := u - \arctan(2y') - (y^2+y)$$

around $y(0)=y'(0)=u(0)=0$

I computed the partial derivatives of $f$ with respect to $y,y',u$ to arrive at:

$$\Delta  y'' = \Delta u + f_{y}(0,0,0)\Delta y + f_{y'}(0,0,0)\Delta y' = 
\Delta u - \Delta y - 2\Delta y'$$

But the solution says this is wrong and it should be
$$\Delta y'' = \Delta u - 2\Delta y' - 2 \Delta y$$
Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reference answer is wrong, your version is correct, $y+y^2$ linearizes to $Δy+2yΔy$, so that at $y=0$ only $Δy$ remains.